# Handling when the GUI changes right before a user clicks or taps

Tags: terminology, input, real-time-updates, refresh

How should I handle the GUI changing just before the user clicks or taps, causing an erroneous input?

I had the idea of ignoring input for 300ms before the input appears, but I'm not sure if this is good UX.

Is there any terminology to describe when this happens?

I asking generally, for example, a user can press R unluckily right after the asking dialog had appeared, and "bye... bye..."

Comment: I see what you mean and it can happen sometimes, essentially between 2 page loads. 
I've never encountered a word to explain this behavior. Yet.

Comment: I have found some good articulation of this [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/34854/103231)

Comment: There's a similar situation with smart TV, cable box, etc. Press `info` and it overlays information about the current program. The message goes away after 30 seconds, or one can press `exit` to clear it immediately. But if one presses `exit` just as it times out, the command applies to the normal screen and messes things up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a name for this... other than "frustrating" ;-)

Generally speaking one shouldn't swap out the UI on the user unless the user does something to trigger it (eg they cramped to see a 6mo vs 3mo chart)

If you have a scenario where the entire UI refreshes... it might be a good idea to white out the UI (~50% white overlay) and throw up a spinner for ~200ms while you fetch the new UI data and swap it in. At least in this scenario the taps during the whiteout are ignored and there is a quick visual clue to the user that the UI is changing.

Comment: You took this too specific. I asking generally, for example, a user can press **R** unluckily right after the asking dialog had appeared, and "bye... bye..."

Comment: Ah ok this is a different scenario. This is like the old windows "i need to reboot, can I reboot now?" reminder dialog. It would pop up every 5 min? And if you're not careful a stray enter would cause a reboot. Ok so my advice would change to this: if the pop up dialog is launched by result of the user action (eg user clicked cancel and thus is an "are you sure"... do nothing, but if you launch a pop up randomly "do you want to do a full HD re-index?" Then disabling the hotkey for a second *may* be ok... I think it would be very scenario specific.